# Execute long running code at program startup after complete GUI is rendered

Tags: python, pyqt

I have an application that can be started from the command line with an optional filename as argument. If present this file should be loaded at startup. Since the processing of the file takes some time, `fileOpen()` blocks the program and shows a loading indicator.

During normal operation this is ok. However, when I try to do the same at startup (as shown below), the outline of the window is present after `show()` but its contents is not rendered up until `app.exec_()`.

My Question: *How do I handle such a situation?*

- I cannot put `fileOpen()` before `app.exec_()` because then the GUI is not yet rendered completely. And I cannot inform the user that the loading is still processed.
- I cannot put ? `fileOpen()` after `app.exec_()` because it would not be executed untill the program finishes.

*Example Code:*

```
def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QApplication()
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    if args.filename:
        mainwindow.fileOpen(args.filename)
    ret_val = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret_val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='(optional) file to load at startup')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say: **the GUI is not yet rendered completely**?

Comment: Try to call qApp.processEvents() inside fileOpen()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that a single-shot timer can solve this problem, but I have only tested it on Linux with the Openbox window manager, so I cannot guarantee that it will work on all platforms. You may need to adjust the duration of the timeout to get this to work on your system.

Here is a simple demo that works for me:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

    def fileOpen(self, path):
        QtWidgets.qApp.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
        QtCore.QThread.sleep(3)
        self.edit.setText(open(path).read())
        QtWidgets.qApp.restoreOverrideCursor()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    mainwindow.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, lambda: mainwindow.fileOpen(__file__))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This solution does not work for Linux(X11)** (see comment and answer by ekhumoro)

Thanks for all the answers. While each of them has some drawbacks (will discuss it below), they brought me to the correct solution:

**Call `qApp.processEvents()` after `mainwindow.show()`**:

```
def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QApplication()
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    qApp.processEvents()
    if args.filename:
        mainwindow.fileOpen(args.filename)
    ret_val = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret_val)
```

Reason: It's exactly what we want to do:

- We want to process events related to the drawing of the main window.
- Then execute our custom code.
- Then continue with the normal event loop.

Discussion of the alternative suggestions:

*Why I don't call `qApp.processEvents()` in `fileOpen()`*: This will be active for all `fileOpen()` calls. Processing other events during a long running file open call, may result in unexpected behavior if the application is not designed with this in mind, e.g. you could issue a second `fileOpen()` while the first is running.

*Why I don't use a timer to perform `fileOpen()`*: I want to execute the code after the GUI is completely loaded but before any user input. A timer just approixates the correct execution order. Additionally, the correct delay can vary depending on CPU, system usage and other factors, making this solution not very robust.

Comment: This solution does not work on X11 (Linux). Calling `qApp.processEvents()` will have no effect there, because the window- manager creates the window-frame asynchronously (so you are waiting for *system*-level events, not *application*-level events). Some kind of timer-based solution is required for a fully cross-platform solution. Of course, you could detect the platform and apply different methods accordingly. (See [X11 Peculiarities](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities) for more details).